# DynamoDB - Unable to read item: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

My code:

def query_consulta_token(holder_id)
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new

```
table_name = "pix_owner_confirmation_token"

holder_id = holder_id

params = {
  table_name: table_name,
  key: {
    holder_id: holder_id,
  },
}

begin
  result = dynamodb.get_item(params)
  puts "%s - %s",
       result.item["holder_id"],
       result.item["address"],
       result.item["token"]
rescue Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ServiceError => error
  puts "Unable to read item:"
  puts "#{error.message}"
  binding.pry
end
```

end

My result:
Unable to read item:
The provided key element does not match the schema

Comment: How is your table primary key defined?

Comment: Chave de partição primária: token (String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you sent to `get_item` specifies a primary key named `holder_id`:

```
params = {
  table_name: table_name,
  key: {
    holder_id: holder_id,
  }
}
```

However, you've commented that your table has a primary key named `token`.  To fix this, you need to provide the name of your primary key in your params:

```
params = {
  table_name: table_name,
  key: {
    token:<your token here>,
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked

But, I need to consult the token, through holder_id, is this possible?

Comment: If `holder_id` is not part of your primary key, your only option will be a `scan` operation.  
Remember that DynamoDB stores your data by it's primary key.  If you want to search for an item by it's primary key, you can use a fast `query` operation.  If you need to search by an attribute of the item that is *not* part of the primary key, you'll need to search across all partitions using the `scan` operation.